# AMP radio input checked not checking

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to check in AMP if radio inputs are checked, but they always return undefined.

This is the html:

```html
    <amp-script layout="container" src="url-to-a-js-script.js">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="some-name" value="Yes">

        <input type="button" id="send-button" value="SEND">
    </form>
    </amp-script>
```

And this is the js file:

```js
    const button = document.getElementById('send-button');
    const radioSelectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="some-name"]');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(radioSelectedValue.checked);
    });
```

The console.log shows undefined.

Comment: What value did you set here: `<meta name="amp-script-src" content=`

Comment: @JayGray, there are several hashes

Comment: @JayGray, I checked and that seems only be needed if I use inline script. It seems to be there as somewhere on the page inline script is used. But my code uses an external file.

Comment: Based on our experience, the document needs the hash provided from chrome-dev and all JS is inline. My suggestion is to start with that baseline design and then experiment with variations.